# I modified my app package name, can i uninstall my previous app from my users in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I modified my application package name and updated the application, Now I want my users to have the new application instead of old one. Is it possible that I can uninstall my previous application while installing this new application or to push a update for old application which uninstall itself and install new one?

Since I modified the package name, do the default update of android will work?

Can some one suggest best way for the same. I can use the same key to sign my new app which i used for the other in case.

Thanks
Pranay

Answer (score 0):

The Android update system is completely based on the package name,sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can not uninstall applications programmatically.

However this seems like a reasnoble solution:

1. Put the app with your new package name on the market.
2. Push an update to the old package, where the application starts, shows a dialog asking the users to upgrade, with a single button that will redirect to the Market page of your new app.

Alternatively, you could have 2 be optional for a period of time, and then "force" users to upgrade after a while.

Comment: but if i take the 2nd option user will have same app 2 times, ie there will be 2 instance of the app. 

this link shows some method to uninstall http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98 is this correct?

Comment: You could have the old version launch the new one if it exists. You can do that by calling the new app main activity.
this way, even if the user have the two of them installed, launching the old one will launch the new one.
As far as I know, there is no way to call the uninstaller without displaying the system confirmation dialog.